# Spring data doesn't throw an exception when database connection is lost

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

We are using spring data cassandra, when connection to cassandra is lost, spring data logs that it is retrying connection, but when repository is called no exception is thrown ?, is there a way to check if the connection is disconnected.

Comment: The connection check should be done by your connection pool handler, which one are you using?

Comment: Is  `spring.data.cassandra.connect-timeout` property useful for you ?